# Two-site disk based backup with migration in Bacula

Tags: backup, bacula

I am setting up a disk based (vchanger) backup system in Bacula, whereby at any given time, two sets of identical data will reside on the disks.  One set of disks will be stored on-site, the other taken off-site.

I've decided the easiest way to do this (and the one that fits my mental model) is to have two storage pools and virtual changes which we will call "Onsite" and "Offsite".  A close inspection of the Bacula manual suggests two ways in which I can cause same job to end up in volumes in both pools:

1. Clone job via Run="%n Level=%l Storage=Offsite"
2. Copy job

Number 2 seems the nicest (exactly the same data, only one job, etc), but I would like some way of kicking off the copy job once the initial job is done.  Can I do this with RunScript?  Or is there another way to achieve this?